# Why is the US version of the first Austin Powers film different to the international version?

Tags: censorship, deleted-scenes, austin-powers

There are several scenes present in the international version of **Austin Powers: International Man Of Mystery** that aren't present in the US (and Australian) version of the film. Overall they total approximately an additional 5 minutes to the film runtime.

The main scenes missing being:

- Two scenes following the death of Dr Evil's henchmen where it cuts to the henchman's friends / family hearing about their demise
- Christian Slater's appearance as a security guard getting hypnotised by Austin

There are other changes / omissions that may be down to local censors (such as for language and violence) but the above scenes are generally just comic in tone.

This was the case for the original theatrical release, the DVD, BluRay and the recent 4K versions too.

I'm not sure if the US version is the 'original' and the rest of the world get the version with deleted scenes added back in, or if the US version had these scenes purposefully removed. Either way, it seems intentional due to the multiple releases still containing the same versions.

I have been unable to find any specific reasoning for why these versions are different. Has there been any statement by anyone involved that clarifies these changes?

Further information on the versions : https://www.movie-censorship.com/report.php?ID=531109

Comment: The US version definitely had a scene where a henchman was due at a birthday party or something just after his demise, and his friends were wondering why he hadn't shown up yet.

Comment: @JohnnyBones Streaming services may use alternative versions, but physical media  versions still have these clipped versions.

Answer (score -3):

Studios will often edit a film differently for different (especially international) audiences.

If something that makes a good scene in New York makes people cringe in London, or vice versa, that's a reason for scenes being included/excluded based on audience location.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: But _why_ do (say) New Yorkers like these scenes while Londoners cringe?

Comment: With respect, you're both essentially asking for either a full film analysis, under the two cohorts' lenses, and then comparing and contrasting. Or is it a scene by scene analysis you're looking for? a 365° consideration of why and when a movie studio or distributor made XY&Z decision at such and such a time? You think they put out press releases for the standard practice of distributing different cuts of a movie. It could've even been affected by the world economy, or political events at the time. Asking a lot to explain standard industry practice, that they'd never tell you the reason to.

Comment: Nobody is asking for a full film analysis. Just citations or evidence as to whether your opinion is based on some sources somewhere or just your own opinions. My question wasn't asking why films in general get amended across international editions, it's specifically about this film and these changes. From my question itself: *"Has there been any statement by anyone involved that clarifies these changes?"*

Comment: So then your answer is "no".

Answer (score -5):

Europeans and Americans have different levels of appreciation for satire and irony.

In Europe these scenes would be near universally seen as a satirical dig at the Hero, and how they are congratulated for cutting down an army of faceless and nameless henchmen.

In the US, some audience demographics would simply see this as being unnecessarily cruel, twisting the knife. While other demographics would see this as an attempt to humanize the villains, which would be seen as unacceptable.

Comment: Do you have a source for these claims?

Comment: What sort of source? Would a published movie review count?

Comment: Do I have a source for America and Europe having different cultures? Would the director's commentary count?

Comment: That specifically "In Europe these scenes would be near universally seen as a satirical dig at the Hero" and "In the US, some audience demographics would simply see this as being unnecessarily cruel". Internet warriors often make sensational claims like this, but in my experience there is very little difference between EU and NA senses of humor.

Comment: People discussing the differences pre-dates the internet, it's why the UK got Monty Python and the US got Friends. Discussing it here would be thread drift. There were two versions of the movie because the director thought that Europeans would see it differently from Americans.

Comment: "People have discussed it" is not a source. People are fervently nationalistic for no reason.

Comment: " *There were two versions of the movie because the director thought that Europeans would see it differently from Americans.*" Now this would be an interesting answer if you have a citation for it. Was it the director? Or was it the distributors? The local censors?

Comment: I don't remember it being specified.

Comment: "People discussing it" isn't a source, it's a description of the content of the source. Which, would be the directors commentary on the DVD.

Comment: If you can cite the specific response in the director's DVD commentary, then that would make this a good answer.